# Applied Linear Algebra | Prove the intersection of two subspaces

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Question: 
Determine whether or not any column in the matrix is a linear combination of other columns. Provide a general method for answering the same question for any n x n matrix A.

[image]

My response:

[image]

I was wondering whether this is the correct process to resolve the above question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid you're on the wrong forum. This one is about the software Mathematica, not the science of mathematics.

Comment: So many ways in M. RowReduce, MatrixRank, dimension of NullSpace, ... and the question looks like homework.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way of doing it, if the matrix is square. If it is rectangular but not square, it is slightly more involved.

Comment: Since you included "applied linear algebra" to your title, this might be the wrong way: The $det=0$ works as long as the matrix is small, or all arithmetic is exact. But for large matrices of floating point numbers, you can make the determinant arbitrarily large for a singular (up to rounding) matrix and arbitrarily small for a full rank matrix. It's one of those things (like inverting a matrix or taking $\left(A.A^{\mathsf{T}}\right)^{-1}$ that work in theory but you don't do them in practice)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for a square matrix, $A$, the rows of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if $\det(A)\neq 0$.  Noting that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, the previous statement can be extended to the columns being linearly independent as well.

Proof:

$\det(A)=0\Leftrightarrow A$ is not invertible $\Leftrightarrow$ when trying to row reduce the augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A & I\end{array}\right]$, the gauss-jordan algorithm fails to complete $\Leftrightarrow$ there is a row of zeroes on the left half of $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A&I\end{array}\right]$during the rowreduction process $\Leftrightarrow$ some nonzero linear combination of rows of $A$ results in zero $\Leftrightarrow$ the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent.

For the more general question of if the rows of an arbitrary rectangular matrix are linearly independent or dependent, apply rowreduction to the matrix.  If the result has a pivot point in every row, then the rows are indeed linearly independent.  Otherwise, they are dependent.  Similarly, if there is a pivot point in every column, the columns are linearly independent, else they are linearly dependent.

You will find that by applying row reduction to your example, it will indeed become the identity matrix, proving their independence.

For information on the Gauss-Jordan row reduction process, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236746/row-reduce-echelon-form-on-3x4-matrix/1236754#1236754) where I outline the process.